# What happens to existing programs and accounts when you push updates with anchor?

Tags: anchor, redeploy

I'm trying to understand the best way to continuously deploy and update programs made by anchor.

From what I understand, If I create a program with anchor I can deploy the code to the network and it'll create new accounts.

But what if I want to add/update/delete methods or features?

Is there a difference between deploying the updated program using `anchor deploy` vs. `anchor upgrade`? What happens to the existing accounts if there's an incompatibility?

Any details to help understand this process would be appreciated.

Comment: `Is there a difference between deploying the updated program using anchor deploy vs. anchor upgrade?` could be a great separate question! Recommend creating another question for that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All accounts are owned by a program, as defined by its address or public key. This gives that program (and only that program) the right to modify those accounts.

If you deploy a new version of the program to a new address, it will not own any of those old accounts. There is no straightforward migration path. Migration might be complex depending on what the underlying program is, and what the accounts do. It's almost like starting from scratch.

However, you can *update* a program. You can redeploy a program to the same address as long as you are the program update authority. This new code will still own the accounts that the old code did. If your new code has *changed* how you want to treat these accounts, you need to handle that in the code itself.

It would generally be *strongly* recommended that updates to a program are *backwards compatible* both for interpreting existing accounts and for external invocations. That is:

- Only add methods (don't remove any)
- Only add parameters (don't remove any)
- Don't make a previously optional parameter not mandatory
- Only add structs, avoid changing existing ones (ie accounts)

If you've got upgraded versions of existing methods that break some of these rules, its *much* better to add a new method than creating a whole new program as there is no simple mechanism for migrating accounts from one program to another.

Think of your program as both a public API (avoid changing external interface in breaking ways) and a database without 'alter' commands (avoid changing underlying data structs). If you can't build an upgrade within those constraints, consider a whole new program address and the pain that comes with it.